# Converting two JSON files into pandas.DataFrame at once -> ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'list'>

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to POST two JSON files together in postman from which I can create two DataFrame objects `guccibag` and `dataprice` using `pandas.read_json()`.

As I was trying this locally, I am keep getting the ValueError when when doing pd.read_json:

`ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'list'>`

**code to extract two DataFrame objs**

```py
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.read_json("./api/guccibag.json")

with open("./api/test.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

gcbag = pd.read_json(data["guccibag"]) # error occurs
gcdata = pd.read_json(data["dataprice"])
```

This way, I hoped the `dataprice` object would be extracted as the following image:
[dataprice df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lBSW.png)

Extracting part works fine when I `pd.read_json` two files separately from `guccibag.json` and `dataprice.json`, but I'm struggling to find a way to send these two JSON files in one POST method.

**JSON format I'm trying to POST:**

```json
    {
      "guccibag": [
        {
          "CODE": "474575 2UZCN",
          "TITLE(KOR)": "홀스빗 1955 미니 토트 탑핸들백 명품 이너백 백인백 구찌 GG 645453 맞춤",
          "TITLE(ENG)": "gg marmont multicolor mini top handle bag",
          "LINEUP(KOR)": "GG 마몽",
          "NAME(KOR)": "GG 멀티컬러 미니 백",
          "PRICE": 598800
        },
        {
          "CODE": "474575 2UZCN",
          "TITLE(KOR)": "홀스빗 1955 미니 토트 탑핸들백 명품 이너백 백인백 구찌 GG 645453 맞춤",
          "TITLE(ENG)": "gg marmont multicolor mini top handle bag",
          "LINEUP(KOR)": "GG 마몽",
          "NAME(KOR)": "GG 멀티컬러 미니 백",
          "PRICE": 598800
        },
        {
          "CODE": "474575 2UZCN",
          "TITLE(KOR)": "홀스빗 1955 미니 토트 탑핸들백 명품 이너백 백인백 구찌 GG 645453 맞춤",
          "TITLE(ENG)": "gg marmont multicolor mini top handle bag",
          "LINEUP(KOR)": "GG 마몽",
          "NAME(KOR)": "GG 멀티컬러 미니 백",
          "PRICE": 598800
        }
      ],
      "dataprice": [
        {
          "PID": 83150012310,
          "TITLE": "홀스빗 1955 미니 토트 탑핸들백 명품 이너백 백인백 구찌 GG 645453 맞춤",
          "PRICE": 23800
        },
        {
          "PID": 54687011345,
          "TITLE": "구찌 홀스빗 1955 미니 탑 핸들 숄더백 645453 92TCG 8563 - 645453 92TCG 8563",
          "PRICE": 877200
        },
        {
          "PID": 28117343440,
          "TITLE": "[라벨루쏘] [구찌] 645453 92TCG 8563 홀스빗 미니 탑 핸들백",
          "PRICE": 877200
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `pd.json_normalize`instead. Your data is already parsed as dictionary and is no longer a json text.

```
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.read_json("./api/guccibag.json")

with open("./api/test.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

gcbag = pd.json_normalize(data["guccibag"])
gcdata = pd.json_normalize(data["dataprice"])
```

output (`gcbag`):

|  | CODE | TITLE(KOR) | TITLE(ENG) | LINEUP(KOR) | NAME(KOR) | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 474575 2UZCN | 홀스빗 1955 미니 토트 탑핸들백 명품 이너백 백인백 구찌 GG 645453 맞춤 | gg marmont multicolor mini top handle bag | GG 마몽 | GG 멀티컬러 미니 백 | 598800 |
| 1 | 474575 2UZCN | 홀스빗 1955 미니 토트 탑핸들백 명품 이너백 백인백 구찌 GG 645453 맞춤 | gg marmont multicolor mini top handle bag | GG 마몽 | GG 멀티컬러 미니 백 | 598800 |
| 2 | 474575 2UZCN | 홀스빗 1955 미니 토트 탑핸들백 명품 이너백 백인백 구찌 GG 645453 맞춤 | gg marmont multicolor mini top handle bag | GG 마몽 | GG 멀티컬러 미니 백 | 598800 |

Comment: thank you! that solved my question. However, how would I approach this problem so I can use a pure json text as input, not parsed as a dictionary, to do the same extraction?

Comment: You need to just give the path of your json file and it will read it. But the json structure might cause issue. For instance in your example, only values under the `guccibag` key should exist in the json file in form of list. With your example you have more control over the data and data structure.